# Numpy vectorize function to operate on rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Suppose I want to vectorize a function `f` as follows, so that it is applied row-wise to a matrix:

```
f_vec = np.vectorize(
     f,
     signature = '(m,n)->m'
)
```

`f_vec` should apply `f` to each row of the input matrix and return the result vector. However, I get an error:

```
ValueError: not a valid gufunc signature: (m,n)->m
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remember that "[t]he [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: `np.vectorize` code is readable Python.  In the case of a signature like this it uses `ndindex` to iterate on dimension `m`, passing arrays of size `n` to your function, expecting back a single value.  `np.array([f(row) for row in arr])` should be just as fast or faster (less overhead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using `(m,n)->(m)` as the signature because I thought `signature` was supposed to be the signature of the *vectorized* function. However, it's actually supposed to be the signature of the `pyfunc`! So in my case, the signature would be `(n)->()` for `f`, yielding `(m,n)->(m)` for `f_vec`. In other words, this code works:

```
f_vec = np.vectorize(f, signature='(n)->()')
```

This says that `f` takes a vector to a scalar, which means `f_vec` takes a matrix to a vector.

Comment: Just to help future readers - using your numenclature, I think your signature should be `(n)->()`, not `(m)->()`. It still works because numpy just wants any letter there, but to fit with your explanation, it is the dimension `n` that is being eliminated.